# How to setup a custom shortcut to toggle auto suspend setting?

Tags: 22.04, shortcut-keys, suspend

I run python scripts that sometimes take several hours to complete. I don't want the laptop to suspend while the script is running. But I want the monitor to turn off based on default setting. How can I do this with a shortcut? I want to toggle "auto suspend" "when plugged in" to "Never" when I use the shortcut.

I tried to use [caffeine](https://linuxmasterclub.com/caffeine/) but it does not let me to turn off the screen. Other app based suggestions are also welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following commands to turn "suspend" off using a shortcut key, respectively for when on AC and when on battery:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'nothing'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'nothing'
```

Change the final argument to `'suspend'` to restore the behavior to auto-suspend. Change `set` by `reset` and leave out the argument to restore the setting to factory default.